# Implementing efficient multithreaded file I/O in C++

Tags: c++, boost, io, boost-asio

I'm currently developing a custom cross-platform file server (**C++, boost**). Obviously, it is going to do *a lot* of reading from and writing to HDD. To further complicate the matters, it is also going to be multithreaded and to use asynchronous socket I/O (with asio).

Now, I wonder, are there any well-known practices, patterns or approaches I can use? Maybe some existing libraries or something? I can try and develop it from scratch, of course, but it does feel like reinventing a wheel. Any generic recommendations will be appreciated as well.

Comment: Spend your money on fast disks and a profiler, not development time.

Comment: Do you intend to deal with thread contention on the same file?  Or are threads 1:1 with files?

Comment: Yes, a file can be accessed by several threads

Answer (score -2):

Few threads  I have seen on quick Googling. Please check if this helps or not.

- [Multithreaded file I/O](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/220300055?pgno=1)
- [Pthread tutorial](http://randu.org/tutorials/threads/)
- [Leader and follower pattern for efficient multi-threaded I/O](http://www.kircher-schwanninger.de/michael/publications/lf.pdf)

Comment: when he said he is using boost, why not use boost threads instead of pthreads ?

Comment: Well, I'm already familiar with multithreading. What I'm concerned about is implementing efficient multithreaded file I/O.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. Presumably the OP already looked on google himself. He (and I) really want an answer that is specific to implementing multithreaded file I/O